# Page not found! The current URL, polls/, didn't match any of ... patterns

Tags: python, django

Друзья, привет. 
Вопрос наверняка тривиальный. 
Прохожу урок по [документации django](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/intro/tutorial03.html):

Появляется ошибка при переходе по:
    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^polls/ ^S [name='index']
    ^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='detail']
    ^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$ [name='results']
    ^polls/ ^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$ [name='vote']
    ^admin/

The current URL, polls/, didn't match any of these.
```

мой ~mysite\polls\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^S', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

~mysite\mysite\urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

~mysite\polls\views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls")

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You are looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You are looking at the results of question %s"
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You are voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

При этом по другим url:

```
.../polls/5/
.../polls/5/results/
.../polls/5/vote/
```

переходит без ошибок. Все отлично. С чем может быть связано такое поведение?
Буду благодарен за совет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас тут

```
url(r'^S', views.index, name='index'),
```

Стоит `S` вместо `$`.

Comment: спасибо @Vadim. Невнимательно списал пример. Чем проверять обычно такие синтаксические ошибки в редакторе?

Comment: Это был вполне корректный код, такое ничем не проверить

Comment: Да, вам верно прокомментировали, это не *синтаксическая*, а *смысловая* ошибка, никакой редактор, увы, не поймет, что вы имели ввиду не то, что написали.